# How to register click event for ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html i have

```
<input type="text" name="post[price]" id="productUpdate" class="test" disabled />
<div class="abs-locator" id="eventDrive"></div>
```

Here is my css

```
.abs-locator{
  width: 17.8%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -29px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 27px;
}
```

I need to perform click event when hidden input box is clicked

Here is my js

```
$('#eventDrive').on('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

But here nothing happens. Why this is happening and how to resolve it

Comment: "I need to perform click event when hidden input box is clicked", dont get it, sorry. How can you click on someting invisible ?

Comment: Thats why i created a div with absolute positioning on the input

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/B2Bcf/2/

Comment: @RafH The above `input` and `div` are dynamically loaded with ajax. I need to perform click event on the id `eventDrive`. But it doesn't firing event

Comment: @Seting as I understand you need to trigger click function on `#eventDrive` when `#productUpdate` is clicked yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like :

```
$(document).on('click', '#eventDrive', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Downvote, because this will not work on disabled input. Please check it.

Comment: Is `#eventDrive` a "disabled input" in the OP context ?

Comment: As said in OP context, he needed to trigger `$('#eventDrive').click()` when `$('#productUpdate')` is clicked. but this input is disabled and disabled input doesn't trigger mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

To have a click event on Ajax loaded content you have to register the event on the container. I would do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#eventDrive', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

This way the click listener will be registered on the whole document, and every time you click it will check if you clicked on the #eventDrive, even if that element didn't exist at the time when you registered the listener.

Comment: Don't really understand the down-vote, what's wrong with this?

Comment: same here, dont get it

Answer (score 0):

Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will propagate an event originating from the disabled element up the DOM tree, so event handlers could be placed on container elements.

I can suggest small solution for that. This is not best practise, but will solve your problem:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
    <input id="productUpdate" name="post[price]" type="text" disabled />
    <div class="inputOverflow" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".inputOverflow").click(function (evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
});​
```